# How to create a dropdown menu on hovering the mouse over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This my jQuery code for displaying a dropdown menu on hovering over an image. `Imgbtn_Dsp` is the id of the image and `nav_menu` is the id of the list, but it's not working.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dropdownlist Hover</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $('#Imgbtn_Dsp').mouseover(function() {
        $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <img src="~/Image/Display.png" / id="Imgbtn_Dsp">
      <div id="nav_menu">
        <ul>
          <li id="l1">AAAAA</li>
          <li>BBBBB</li>
          <li>CCCCC</li>
          <li>DDDDD</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your script like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#nav_menu').hide();
            $('#Imgbtn_Dsp').mouseover(function () {
                $('#nav_menu').slideDown();
            });
            $('#Imgbtn_Dsp').mouseleave(function () {
                $('#nav_menu').slideUp();
            });
        });
     </script>
```

You can see the cod in action in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar6bc938/).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of div and modify `ul` like this if you want to work it properly ;)

```
<ul id="nav_menu" style="display: none">
    <li id="l1">AAAAA</li>
    <li>BBBBB</li>
    <li>CCCCC</li>
    <li>DDDDD</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be done without jquery. all you have to do is define parent container of image and list set some css.

```
<div class="parentDIV">
 <img src="~/Image/Display.png" / id="Imgbtn_Dsp">
  <div id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="l1">AAAAA</li>
      <li>BBBBB</li>
      <li>CCCCC</li>
      <li>DDDDD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

now define some css:-

```
.parentDIV{position:relative}
#nav_menu{position:absolute;
          left:0;top:99%;display:none;}

.parentDIV:hover #nav_menu{display:block}
```

hopefully you will find it useful